# How to modify npm scripts in package.json for Windows

Tags: npm-scripts

Below script can be executed in MacOS.

How to change this script to run in Windows?

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently -kill-others-on-fail \"cd hosting; npm run watch\" \"cd functions; npm run watch\" \"cd hosting; npm run start\" ",
    "deploy": "cd hosting; npm run build; cd ../functions; npm run build; firebase deploy",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "setup": "npm install; cd hosting; npm install; cd ../functions; npm install;",
},
```

Comment: Did you try `npm run <start, deploy etc>`?

Comment: I would like to ask how to change the script according to windows. When I run < npm run setup> . I get error. It is due to the path convention is different between mac os and windoes.

Comment: npm commands needs to be converted for windows